# Re-filling an array when it is null

Tags: javascript

Hi there I wonder if you could help.

I have a random number generator which when you press a button reduces the amount of numbers in the array ie. the one that got randomised has now been used and is removed.

```
var crds = Math.floor((math.random()*myArray.length));

myArray = ["2","4","6","8","10","100","20","Bingo!"];
Array.prototype.removeByIndex = function(index){ 
    this.splice(index,1)
}
```

I have not included the attachements to button presses but this code tells the story - When the button is pressed it splices the array via index of the number randomised. What I do not know how to do is to re-initialise the array when all the numbers have been removed.

`if(myArray[crds]==null){
    myArray = ["2","4","6","8","10","100","20","Bingo!"];
}`

any help would be appreicated

Comment: When the elements are removed, the array is empty, not null. Check the length property to see if it's empty.

Comment: Do what @jeffman said every time you click the button.  This check is very important.

Comment: Cheers for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (myArray.length == 0) {
    myArray = ["2", "4", "6", "8", "10", "100", "20", "Bingo!"];
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WkaV4/

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Thats exactly what I needed! Big lesson!!